# Synchronising Navigation in Images of the Same Dimensions Within Different Windows

Tags: gimp

I have three separate images loaded up in GIMP and I want to synchronise navigation and zoom levels across each window so that I can easily analyse the same region of each image without having to adjust the navigation panel three times.

All of the images are of the same thing and have the same dimensions but with different processing applied, and each image has 6 layers which I don't want to merge as they all contain different information which I want to hide or show depending on a number of factors.  I realise that I could have all of the layers in the same file and just create a New View for each set of layers, but I want to keep them separate for various reasons.

I have the three windows tiled vertically for comparison purposes but being able to link their navigation would speed up the process tremendously.

Is this possible either with or without an additional toolbox/plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with current GIMP, using standard GIMP plug-ins. 
The plug-in API does not expose any calls for the program UI, but for creating and destroying a new view for an image. There is no way of setting the zoom level or offsets for each window.

While it is possible, in theory, to change GIMP's code to perform this, programming this into GIMP would be complicated.

So, your workflow, while a reasonable request, is not easy to comply with. 
What I can think off is to customize an external image viewer that could load your desired images, and sync navigation and zoom level for the three of them. Then, there could be made a GIMP script that on one key-press could export the images in different windows and launch this external viewer. The viewer itself would have to be written, though, maybe using something like this as base:
 http://effbot.org/zone/simple-image-viewer.htm

If you use GIMP compiled from GIT, I've just added a way to have
the display offsets in the title bar. At least that will allow you to 
synchronize both windows by hand.  Check the title bar codes
at [How to quickly know layer dimensions in Gimp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042093/how-to-quickly-know-layer-dimensions-in-gimp)

Comment: Thanks, very thorough answer indeed, I have a workaround using Matlab's axis command, but it's just not as good as being able to use GIMPs layers since GIMP was made specifically for images and Matlab was made for matrices